# Scanf not being picked up inside a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, eof

So I wrote this code with a while loop that continues until an EOF. The problem with it is that it doesn't pick up the first input for the scanf function. Basically, I have to press "Enter" once before the program works as intended. How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int firstNumber, secondNumber, i;
    double firstFactorial = 1, secondFactorial = 1;
    while(getchar() != EOF){
        scanf("%d %d", &firstNumber, &secondNumber);
        for(i = 1; i <= firstNumber; ++i){
            firstFactorial = firstFactorial * i;
        }
        for(i = 1; i <= secondNumber; ++i){
            secondFactorial = secondFactorial * i;
        }
        printf("%lf\n", firstFactorial + secondFactorial);
        firstFactorial = 1;
        secondFactorial = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mixing `getchar()` and `scanf()` seems like a bad plan because `getchar()` consumes input.

Comment: You fix it by putting the `scanf` call inside the `while` statement, e.g. `while (scanf(...) == 2) { ... }` The return value from `scanf` is the number of successful conversions. It should be 2 in your code, since the format string has two conversion requests.

Comment: BTW, assuming that an `int` is 32 bits, this code will only work for inputs up to 12. `13!` is about 6.2 billion, which is too big for a 32 bit number.